# Error Using Mysql In Mathematica

Tags: databaselink, sql

I'm using Mathematica, and accessing mysql through mysql (Connector/J).
When I try to update a field in my table using `WHERE` statement, all the rows get updated

```
SQLUpdate[conn2, "Table", {"pos"}, {"Value1"}, Equal[SQLColumn["word"], "Value2"]]

SQLSelect[conn2, "Recipe.OptOutWordInIngredient"]
```

I thought it had to do with not using `SQLStringMatchQ`.
However, when I use `SQLStringMatchQ`

```
SQLSelect[conn2, "Table", SQLStringMatchQ[DatabaseLink`SQLColumn["word"], "value"]]
```

I get the following error:

> The value SQLStringMatchQ[acid ,value] cannot be converted to a value in an SQL statement.*

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a tip -- I use Mathematica and MySQL together every day, and I use `SQLExecute[]` rather than `SQLUpdate[]` or `SQLSelect[]`. This way I can test the SQL directly in the mySQL workbench and make sure it's doing what I want before I put in in Mathematica.

Comment: @MichaelStern I do the same. I was/am very interested to go even further and systematically apply SQL to data massaging and retrieval tasks within *Mathematica* in the same way the R package ["sqldf"](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf) does.

Answer (score 1):

Both these methods of updating work and produce the same results.

```
SQLUpdate[conn2, "Table", {"pos"}, {"Value1"},
   Equal[SQLColumn["word"], "Value2"]]

SQLUpdate[conn2, "Table", {"pos"}, {"Value1"},
   SQLStringMatchQ[SQLColumn["word"], "Value2"]]
```